# Throw exeception when use support library for API > 11 in android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

```
05-02 13:58:38.374: W/dalvikvm(13249): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4104e438)
05-02 13:58:38.384: E/AndroidRuntime(13249):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2067)
05-02 13:58:38.384: E/AndroidRuntime(13249):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
05-02 13:58:38.384: E/AndroidRuntime(13249):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
05-02 13:58:38.384: E/AndroidRuntime(13249):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1203)
05-02 13:58:38.384: E/AndroidRuntime(13249):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4882)
05-02 13:58:38.384: E/AndroidRuntime(13249):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2031)
```

The above exception is shown when I add the v7 appcompat library to the project. **But it work fine on the emulator at version 2.3 .**

This is how I add the library

1. import the project of adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat
2. right click my project , propertity -> android -> add -> select the project I just imported
3. In the values/ style.xml 
   Change to  `<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">`
4. Modify all activity to the ActionBarActivity

I even comment out the getActionBar/ getSupportActionBar, it still throw exception. How to fix that? Thanks

Comment: why do you need to use Support library fro api level 11 and greater?. if your min sdk is below 11 then use appcompat

Comment: The project is for 2.3 to 4.x , if I import it and extend the ActionBarActivity, then no matter what version I android use, it is still using the support library

Comment: You mean in my program I can check to import it? Sorry I am first time using this. Thanks for helping

Comment: is that the full stacktrace??

Comment: yes. that's all . I tried other class using Activity , it will not throw exception

Comment: no it should work. post the relevant code and manifest

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51857/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-user782104)

Comment: Thanks, the problem is due to the style not yet change in values_14